# i just installed react native using choco and i keep getting this error everytime i run "npx react-native run-android" on cmd

Tags: react-native

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.
- Try:                                                                                                                  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\gusta\Desktop\lyftclone\lyft\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\gusta\Desktop\lyftclone\lyft\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\gusta\Desktop\lyftclone\lyft\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\gusta\Desktop\lyftclone\lyft\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```